# Earning salary from USA remotely from New Zealand?

Tags: united-states, taxes, income-tax, new-zealand

I'm from the beautiful country New Zealand.

My problem is:

1. I am accepting the work remotely,
2. Some of the companies from USA are willing (and really interested) to provide me job to work remotely and pay me salary on monthly basis

So, I request to please look at my questions as follows:

1. Can companies from USA give job to me (I am from New Zealand)?
2. If so, what are the legal documents I have to provide to the USA for any taxes?
3. Will I have to pay tax to New Zealand Government?

Also, please let me know what kind of financial/legal adviser can help me for my present situation; I am willing to pay fees if required.

Comment: I removed your request for specific service provider recommendations; that part of your question is off-topic for this site.

Answer (score 4):

> Can the companies from USA give job to me (I am from New Zealand)?

Job as being employee - may be tricky. This depends on the labor laws in New Zealand, but most likely will trigger "nexus" clause and will force the employer to register in the country, which most won't want to do.

Instead you can be hired as a contractor (i.e.: being self-employed, from NZ legal perspective).

> If so, what are the legal documents i have to provide to the USA for any taxes?

If you're employed as a contractor, you'll need to provide form W8-BEN to your US employer on which you'll have to certify your tax status. Unless you're a US citizen/green card holder, you're probably a non-US person for tax purposes, and as such will not be paying any tax in the US as long as you work in New Zealand. If you travel to the US for work, things may become tricky, and tax treaties may be needed.

> Will I have to pay tax to New Zealand Government?

Most likely, as a self-employed. Check how this works locally.

---

As for recommendations, since these are highly subjective opinions that may change over time, they're considered off-topic here. Check on Yelp, Google, or any local NZ professional review site.

Comment: The most difficult part of this is that before you can submit a W8-BEN, you need to get a US taxpayer number, and to get a US taxpayer number you need to submit various documents that have been "notarized" by a "notary public". Unfortunately there aren't many of these around outside the US (see http://americannotary.co.uk). I got it done on a visit to the US (just walk into any bank), but it would otherwise have meant a trip to the nearest US embassy.

Answer (score 0):

> 3. Will I have to pay tax to New Zealand Government?

Yes. You must register for GST as well, if you will be making over the threshold (currently $60,000). That's probably a bonus for you, as your home office expenses will mostly include GST, but your income will most likely be [zero-rated](http://www.ird.govt.nz/gst/additional-calcs/calc-spec-supplies/calc-zero/calc-zero.html#exportedservices). Check with an accountant or with the IRD directly.

Just be certain to put aside enough money from each payment to cover income tax, GST and ACC. You will get a *very* large bill in your second year of business.